# Why does my bubble sort function adds 0 to my vector array although it wasn't in my array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, bubble-sort

I want to create a sorting void function that modified directly its parameters. It is bubble sort. The function works perfectly but for some unknown reason it keeps on adding '0' as the first element. Even if 5 is the smallest int, 0 gets added. I tried debugging and it turns out that the bubble sort function adds 0 as a new elements though I never specified the program to do so. The whole array becomes spoilt. Last element is no longer 100 but 99 instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//generate random num
int myRandom(int max){return rand()%max;}

//generate num range
void genVec(vector<int> &v,int min,int max,int step=1){
    for (int i=min;i<=max;i+=step){
        v.push_back(i);
    }
}

//bubble sort
void bsort(vector<int> &v,int len){
    //make sure focus array has more than 2 elements to compare and swap
    if (len>=1){
        int accum{1};
        for (vector<int>::iterator itr=v.begin();itr!=v.end()-(v.size()-len);itr++){
            if (*itr>v[accum]){
                swap(v[accum-1],v[accum]);
            }
            accum ++;
        }
        //re-call
        bsort(v,len-1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    vector<int> values;
    //generate num range
    genVec(values,5,100);
    srand(time(0));
random_shuffle(values.begin(),values.end(),myRandom );
    bsort(values,values.size());
    
    //print all array elements
    for (int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
        cout << values[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
0
5
6
7
8
9
.
.
.
97
98
99

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Since you've done the debugging, and determined that the problem is that it "adds 0 as a new elements", then it seems that this is a simple matter of figuring out why, and fixing it?

Comment: `if (len>=1)` should be `if (len>1)`. Unrelated, you should try this with iterators, I think you'll find it much more intuitive.

Comment: On the first call, when `len == v.size()`, the loop makes `v.size()` iterations. `accum` starts at 1 and is incremented to `v.size()`. Whereupon `v[accum]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm saying use *only* iterators and lose all the array indexing entirely. I.e. [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/14h681WdG).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah ok, thanks.